Can a nuke be safely destroyed mid-flight without triggering its explosion?
Scenario: a thermonuclear warhead loaded on a ballistic missile has been launched at a target and is in the descent phase of its flight. The target happens to be an artificial intelligence capable of synthesizing artificial constructs of any shape, size, function, and material in a matter of seconds, and has access to an essentially bottomless supply of energy to use as it pleases. The AI's life is not at risk, but it cares deeply for organic lifeforms, and it would like to avoid as much damage to Earth's biosphere as possible. It could simply shoot the bomb out of the sky, but that would surely cause it to detonate in the upper atmosphere, possibly still causing extensive fallout damage.
The AI's plan is thus: If it can create a laser beam of sufficient power, it can disintegrate the warhead so fast that the rapidly-accelerating fission reaction causing the explosion has no time to happen, reducing the warhead to a cloud of individual atoms. Is this something that is capable of happening? And if so, what would be the effects of the disparate atoms of a thermonuclear warhead dispersing in the higher areas of the thermosphere?

That's not something we can do today. It might not be doable at all. You need the heat the entire warhead simultaneously and a laser heats beginning at the point of impact. That hasn't stopped a lot of scifi from implementing the ubiquitous disintegrator ray. What's stopping you from using the idea? Knowing that we can't actually do this (you probably suspected that), what's the real problem?

Shooting a bomb out of the sky doesn't cause it to detonate with a nuclear yield.  That's the whole basis of ABM missiles.  You'll scatter some radioactive debris, but that will always be the consequence of destroying the weapon, and the resultant debris will be more concentrated than aerosolizing the missile.

More generally, you can set off a (conventional) bomb in a nuclear weapons storage rack, and none of the resulting explosions are going to be nuclear, just difficult to clean up.

(Also, if the AI can manifest anything of any composition anywhere it wants, why not manifest a steel wall with zero momentum right in front of the missile?  Or bisecting the missile straight through the warhead?)

@jdunlop Now there's a word not often applied like this. Aerosolize. Aerosolize. That word needs to show up in a made-for-streaming movie somewhere. Like one of the Sharknados. They aerosolized the sharks inside the tornado. There was lots of dry cleaning involved. I love it. :-)

So it can create anything it wants and has unlimited energy. Then why is it a question whether it can send so much energy at an incoming missile that the missile vaporizes? Seems like the only limit is your imagination. There's nothing to stop it from even ridiculously-scaled brute-force solutions like creating a million high-powered lasers aimed at the target.

If it's that powerful, why does it let the enemy get a nuclear missile off the ground in the first place?

This question amounts to, "can my all-powerful god do this?" to which the answer is always and obviously "yes". With unlimited energy and absolute control of matter, anything that is physically possible can be achieved. Unclear why the AI would even keep the bomb on the planet, though, they can just make a giant boot to kick it into the Sun and avoid any negative consequences.

In general, it's actually quite hard to cause a sub-critical mass (i.e. what's inside of a nuke "at rest") become supercritical. Anything that disrupts this process before it's triggered will result in a heavy, slightly radioactive paperweight falling to Earth rather than a nuclear explosion. Fewer pieces are actually preferable.

@JBH Somewhat tangential, but I'd point out in more "realistic" scifi stories, a disintegrator ray isn't simply an unfathomably powerful laser but a beam that acts on a pseudoscientific principle to deconstruct the target at the molecular/(sub)atomic level, usually involving a field or chain reaction of some kind. For instance, OP's AI could stop the missile by enveloping it in a field that disrupts the strong nuclear force, causing protons and neutrons to wander away from each other and ultimately reducing the entire missile to a dense cloud of (probably highly energetic) hydrogen and helium.

@Matthew Exactly. Basically the compression explosive (which is just normal bomb explosive) has to be symmetrical in order to crush the subcritical core enough to make it briefly supercritical and trigger a nuclear explosion.  If the bomb is struck from outside, or even if the compression charge doesn't trigger correctly, it'll essentially squirt the nuclear core out the side instead of compressing it.  Which is a mess, but not a thermonuclear mess.

If you can synthesise literally anything and have practically unlimited energy then you could make some kind of gadget that flies up to the missile and attaches aerodynamic control surfaces to it, diverting it to a different location where it will either detonate harmlessly or be captured whole. Either way, that prevents radioactive material from being scattered into the atmosphere (because if it detonates as designed it will use up all the fission fuel), so it's a better solution than just disintegrating it. Matching velocity with it will require some serious rocket science, but that's ok.

Yes, the plan is doable
As mentioned in comments and other answer(s), it is exactly possible to prevent nuclear explosion of a warhead if given enough power. What laser would do is just superheat the target, and since its power is said to be arbitrary, you might as well use a kinetic warhead hitting the target with similar effects. After all, say 1 GJ over a 1 fs in laser energy is about equal to a very sparse kinetic device flying at speed of light. If the warhead was not in the process of triggering itself when the AI's weapon would hit it, it will pretty harmlessly turn into hot plasma.
The question has one thing amiss - where are the AI's production mechanisms located? If they are on the planet's surface, then blasting the missile off with a laser, even if charged beyond measure, might cause some serious problems to the atmosphere in close vicinity to the laser's emitter. At the very least, high energy laser beam causes the atoms in the space where it flies to become ionized, creating an opaque plasma volume which would get further heated with subsequent energy transferred by the laser emission. This makes normal "long pulsed" lasers impractical for atmospheric combat, for example, forcing others to use short pulses with their lasers. Blasting it off with a kinetic weapon with a speed of several dozen km/s (railguns) would also cause some sinister shockwaves, with a possibility of that kinetic projectile to be destroyed prior to impact. So your AI would likely still deploy an anti-ballistic missile in order to destroy that warhead, thus the warhead would not be turned into plasma, but into bits and pieces, which would fall down somewhere without triggering nuclear explosions. This kind of counts anyway, and doesn't largely alter the result.
Fusion part is harmless
Fusion reagents are Li and H-2 or deuterium, which are non-radioactive, H-2 is even normally universally present in the ecosystem, while Li would quickly oxidize and turn into trace contaminants, especially if the warhead was destroyed somewhere very high above the surface. Whatever construction materials used in that warhead, including conventional explosives, would also get reduced to less harmful substances and also spread over a huge area, rendering the chemical pollution levels down to trace.
Fission part will cause elevated radiation levels
In fact, if the warhead would have some U-238 as fission part (see Tsar Bomba's planned fission "fourth" stage), that won't actually do detectable harm, even chemical contamination won't be noticeable. But U-235 due to it releasing high energy neutrons at fission will cause local radiation increase, and should there happen to be a solid piece of fission core landing somewhere, it will be harmful to the local environment and humans nearby. If the warhead would be blown up conventionally, there would be several hundred noticeable pieces of uranium scattered over several thousand square miles, threatening some of the local populace, and the dust-sized or smaller particles would be gradually deposited downwind from the blast, providing a surface source of gamma radiation that would depend on the warhead's designed power and several other unaccountable factors like weather, presense of rivers, dustbowls and stuff.

Fissile material is an alpha source, not gamma. Which is bad, because alpha, while harmless outside the body, will almost certainly cause cancer if eaten or inhaled. So, the AI will want to send decontamination teams with alpha detectors (Geiger counters, possibly others).

If the fissile core disintegrates you'd basically be triggering an aerial https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirty_bomb [just adding a reference to what your last paragraph describes]

@Hobbamok I think not exactly, as a dirty bomb is something that did blow up, while disintegrating the core without actual explosion would just contaminate the land with uranium with no fission products (say Cs-137). This contamination might be easier to get rid of.

@Vesper the bomb part about dirty bombs is rather irrelevant. The explosion only serves to spread the contaminants. There are no fission products to speak of either. And whether the payload (in  the rocket case unintentional) is spread via explosives or supersonic rocket disintegration doesn't matter that much. Yes, overall the particles are probably gonna be a bit bigger and easier to find, but also wider (and less predicteably) spread out, so it depends on the details how much better which case is. I'd put them at about the same level

@Vesper since you're talking about Cs-137: I am NOT talking about a nuclear explosion. That is NOT what a dirty bomb is. A dirty bomb is just a regular bomb being used to spread radioactive material around the affected area.

Yes, but ...
Fission weapons are triggered by assembling a critical mass of some fissionable material. Fusion weapons are usually triggered by a smaller fission weapon at their core. There are two principal designs for fission weapons, gun type and implosion type. The gun type fires a (subcritical) slug of uranium or plutonium into a (subcritical) sleeve, forming a critical mass out of both. The implosion type uses explosives to crush a hollow shell which is subcritical because of the empty volume inside, and which becomes critical when it is crushed. But the timing of the explosives has to go exactly right so that the mass is crushed into a critical mass and not simply blown into bits.
If you take a rifle, a cannon, or a laser, and shoot at an implosion type nuke, this may or may not trigger the explosive. It will not trigger the explosive with the right timing. The result is effectively a dirty bomb -- a radiological weapon but not a nuclear explosion.
Both uranium and plutonium are chemically toxic metals, in addition to their radioactive decay. Breathing even small amounts of these metal dusts is extremely unhealthy. (Compare the debate and rampant misunderstanding about depleted uranium tank shells. They are not significantly radioactive. They are toxic.)
So your laser would cause the fissionables to "rain down" over the target area. But it would be very widely distributed, without the immediate effects of a nuclear explosion. There may be statistically noticeable increases in cancers in the following years.

An important component of an A-bomb is the containment vessel. This has to withstand the pressure of the atomic explosion for a few crucial milliseconds to let it really get going. Without that the bomb just fizzles: quite a lot of radioactivity but not much boom. A kinetic energy weapon that breaks the containment vessel will prevent most of the atomic chain reaction from happening, even if the rest of the mechanism manages to function.

@PaulJohnson, containment is essential for fusion.  For implosion-type fission bombs, the explosive lenses provide the containment; for gun-type, the mass of the uranium does (it's why gun-type bombs are so much less efficient than implosion-type ones).

@Mark yes, and by destroying the bomb shell you distort the layout of the explosive lenses (and probably their timing as well), so they won't create a supercritical mass. Gun type weapons have AFAIK never been used on long range missiles, countries tend to advance beyond them before developing those.

@Mark Implosion-type nukes need to function at millisecond accuracy. It's pretty much a given that any damage to the structure will at least slightly distort the frame, turning the whole thing into a dud. I'm not sure how sensitive gun-style nukes are, I'd expect them to malfunction because they have to be pretty precise too, but not at the millisecond level so maybe these can withstand more. Still, nukes aren't built for surviving unplanned damage, they're expensive enough as it is, and I'd expect them to malfunction anyway.

Use a nuke, on a Mach 10 rocket
Here is a scenario for you. Your AI does the following...

It builds a conically shaped two-stage rocket



It puts this rocket in a silo, that has a piston at the bottom that can push the rocket out really quickly.

Oh, and for extra oomph, this piston is driven by an explosive charge, that gets the rocket out in about 0.6 seconds.

On launch, the rocket is yeeted out of the silo and the first stage kicks in. This first stage only burns for 1.2 seconds, but it is so powerful that it accelerates the rocket at about 80 g. This first stage accelerates the rocket to about 600-1000 m/s, which is Mach 2 to 3:ish.

The second stage takes over, and it accelerates the rocket even harder, at about 100 g at its peak, and the rocket hurtles towards the target at about Mach 10 top speed.

Zooming through the atmosphere at this magnificent speed tends to do funny things to the air it punches through, leaving behind a plasma trail. Hence the signals from the base station to control this rocket are sent using especially powerful radio transmitters, to get through this glowing plasma trail.
...and, yeah, the rocket is also glowing by now.

At this insane closeure rate, getting a precise hit on the target may be a bit difficult. But fear not, because 'Close' counts with horseshoes, hand grenades, and nukes. Yes, your AI has put a nuke at the top of this rocket. It is a so called "enhanced radiation" weapon, meaning it does not make a huge fireball like normal nukes, but instead a massive burst of neutron radiation. Because — funny enough — nuclear weapons react kind of like humans to large bursts of neutron radiation: they die.
A single digit kiloton nuclear explosion with a neutron bomb high up in the atmosphere is no hazard to anyone on the ground, except — possibly — people getting in the way of the heavily neutron activated debris that comes raining down.


And now, you are rolling your eyes at me, thinking I am a total idiot for suggesting such a totally non-credible scenario.
...and then there is that little niggling voice at the back of your head, wondering why I am so oddly specific about this? "And why is there a picture of the darned thing? Oh... oh no... they didn't... did they?!"
Yes, they did...
They fielded a nuclear armed rocket to shoot down nukes
The Sprint missile, by Martin Marietta, was in service from 1965 to 1975, as a part of the United States' defence against Soviet intercontinental ballistic missiles. All(!) of the insane specs I gave you above, are true.
To watch the Sprint in action, here is a video of it launching (warning: loud music).
In case you want to be more conventional...
...just do massive damage to the incoming missile.
Nukes are not shock-sensitive, they do not detonate from being jostled, impacted or knocked about.
Simply unload massive amounts of explosively propelled shrapnel into the thing
to break the components, and you turn it into a fairly harmless piece of junk.
...that is coming down at you at hypersonic speeds, which is a problem in and of itself, but at least it is not doing its fission/fusion thing.
"But what about the plutonium and such?!"
Plutonium dust is not something you want to breathe, no. Good for you, AIs do not need to breathe.

The small nuke exploding in high atmosphere is still very dangerous. The Compton effect or big EMP can still fry electronics and power lines, causing (house) fires and the like. The nukes in the air can still release many toxic chemicals and radioactive materials. It really seems better to shoot it down with a small kinetic missile than an actual nuke.

I love the "warning, it's loud" on the link to a video of a mach 10 nuclear weapon. Like... i bet it is!

@Trioxidane You are wrong. The service ceiling of the Sprint was 30 km. This is far below the altitude needed to make an EMP, you need to loft the warhead up into the hundreds of kilometers to get the Compton effect. Further, the W66 warhead it was very low yield, only about 2 kilotons. The famed EMP-generating bombs were in the megaton range. And — as mentioned — the W66 was a neutron warhead; the primary radiation was neutrons, not electrons (which you need to get the Compton effect). Finally, with the small yield and very high airbursts, fallout will be dispersed and minimal.

@Trioxidane I agree that using kinetics is better, which I finished the post with (just pointing that out, in case you did not get that far before you rushed into the comments). But your objections to the "Fight Nukes With Nukes" concept were wrong in the 60s and 70s and they are wrong now. Or did you seriously think that you realised something that they did not already consider back then, hm? So if it was you that put in a -1 for these — flawed — reasons... you might want to reconsider that. Plus... the Sprint is just such a mind-blowingly cool system in its abject absurdity. :D

@codeMonkey - to be clear, none of the test-launched Sprints were nuclear-armed.

this is all very useful information! thank you.

It is safer to confuse it than to destroy it
Because of the way nuclear detonators work, just shooting the missile will not detonate it, but it will turn it into a dirty bomb which is still going to harm a lot of people; so, it's not really the best way to prevent collateral from a nuclear ICBM.  Instead, the safest thing you can do is crash land somewhere far away from any populated area: preferably in the ocean where the heavy radioactive particles will quickly sink to the ocean floor where they can not hurt anyone.  This way, the irradiated zone can just be quarantined until the fallout has had some time to break down or sink.
Most ICBMs use a combination of GPS and inertial guidance systems.  Jamming or hijacking GPS will allow you to send the nuke a bit off course, but if GPS places the missile farther off course than the inertial system's margin of error, then the inertial system is designed to take over which means you can only fool a missile into going about 1 mile off course per 1000 miles of range.  While this is normally a win against conventional missiles, nukes only need to get relatively close to a target to cause immeasurable harm. GPS jamming alone will give you maybe 5-10 miles of deviation against an ICMB which can steer a nuke strike from hitting the center of a city to landing somewhere in the outskirts, but that's still not enough to prevent a significant loss of life.
So, to get the rocket to go substantially off course, you need to fool the inertial guidance system which is much harder because it is a self contained system.  That said, the reason IGSs are so inaccurate is that minor, unpredictable variances in wind, atmospheric conditions, and fuel impurities can alter the course of the missile in unexpected ways; however, anything that changes its course by even a few degrees can send them WAY off course.  So instead of trying to shoot the missle down, you need to just give it a push.
One of the key components of an ICBM is the ablative heat shield it needs to re-enter the atmosphere.   Under normal conditions, when if gets into the atmosphere, it burns up symmetrically turning into plasma and bleeding off the excess energy of atmospheric friction. But, if you have an arbitrarily powerful and accurate laser, you could target one side of the heat shield while the missile is still mid flight.  By burning it asymmetrically the heatshield ejects highly energetic reaction mass in one directing turning the missile. Thinking it is still going straight, it will ignore its GPS which now says it is way off course and continue to a target that may now be several degrees from where it should be going.  So instead of landing within a few miles of a major city its new course might lead it over 100 miles off target which is plenty of variance in most cases to land it somewhere that is mostly harmless like the ocean, a barren desert, or mountain range were there are very few people to hurt and little human dependency on the biome.
Furthermore, its now damaged heat shield is also likely to fail on re-entry causing its it's detonator to explode improperly preventing any actual nuclear explosion.

No, plutonium is not suitable material for a "dirty bomb", and it will not "kill a lot of people". Plutonium is a weak alpha emitter, and almost entirely chemically inert in the environment, meaning it does not get about, and do not enter the food chain. Sure, you do not want to breathe Plutonium dust, because that might — possibly — increase you odds of getting lung cancer. But all in all, Plutonium makes for a really [crappy] dirty bomb.

@MichaelK Plutonium is highly carcinogenic and it certainly is know to enter the food supply through groundwater.   It is less toxic than Uranium, yes, but just because a rattlesnake is less poisonous than a death adder does not make it a good idea to get bitten by either.  Also, the OP did not specify the kind of nuke.  While India, Israel, and Russia mostly use Plutonium based nukes, the USA, China, and North Korea use mostly Uranium based nukes.

No. Sorry, but... just no. This. "it certainly is know to enter the food supply through groundwater" is just plain wrong. It is an actinide. It does not dissolve in water. This is stuff you basically just made up and think is true because... well, it is Plutonium, right? It is like Nazis: you can accuse them of anything and everything and everyone will accept it. But... no. It is not this super-toxin, and neither is uranium. Sure, it is a heavy metal... ingesting heavy metal dust is bad for you, no matter if it is Plutonium or Cadmium or whatever. But it is not Evil Black Magic™.

@MichaelK "The current maximum contaminant level (MCL) for gross alpha
particle activity — which includes ... plutonium-239... is 15 picocuries per liter." https://ieer.org/wp/wp-content/uploads/2012/02/13-3.pdf This means that the average nuke contains enough plutonium to contaminate1.3e16 liters of water.  Yes, it is 5000 times safer to drink or eat than to inhale, but it is still incredibly dangerous stuff at the volumes used in nukes.

There are sources that say that plutonium contaminated food does not pose a significant health risk, but that is because those foods are contaminated by very trace amounts of plutonium like you get when burn dirty coal too close to farmland.  The amount of plutonium left by a nuke is many orders of magnitude greater than you get from common industrial processes.

@MichaelK He didn't make anything up, you can ready everything up at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plutonium#Toxicity . Also, while the raw metal does not dissolve, various Pu salts do, and these do form from the metal given the right environmental chemistry. None of this is relevant as the alpha emissions are the real danger, and inhaling dust is much more likely than ingesting.

Make the bomb inert
It is probably true you can instantly vaporise the whole rocket, given you have infinite energy and the ability to create anything you want. You could send out enough neutrinos to do the job, which would cost more power than a supernova. If you want to do as little organic damage as possible it is best not to send out any laser capable of vaporising the rocket instantaneously. Because you're dumping a lot of energy and heat into the atmosphere as well, which can have unintended consequences.
Change the rocket
The very easiest way is to prevent both the explosives as well as the nuclear material to do their function is to change what they are. Both function on being an only semi-stable material. It is stable enough to be stored years on end without becoming inert or going off. If you put it into a certain state, like igniting the blast caps or pushing the nuclear material very close together, it'll rapidly undergo a change to a more stable state. In both these cases an explosion, though one chemical and one nuclear.
On an atomic level both need only a small change to prevent them from exploding. The AI luckily can create any item in seconds, or create a powerful laser. Changing an existing material seems trivial in comparison. The AI can add or remove molecules to the conventional bomb materials so they become stable. They'll become unable to ignite. The nuclear material can get a similar change. From a certain weight everything is nuclear however, so you'll remove parts of the element until it is stable, like lead, or stable enough, like bismuth.
You might think that impossible. They'll detonate the warhead in the air. However, military planners are smart. The AI is near certainly protected against EMP, radiation and much more. Akin to a nuclear bunker. The military knows it can construct even more to withstand a 'regular' nuke. So they try to apply the nuclear force as efficient as possible. A nuclear bunker buster can be shot into the target, or the ground near it, for devastating effect. That requires the missile to come close enough to be edited on the fly. That would be the most safe way to disarm the missile. It is rendered inert without altering the environment with super lasers.
